# VS Code Python TensorBoard integration doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning, vscode-python

The Python extension for VS Code [recently released TensorBoard integration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-february-2021-release/), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Whenever I run "Python: Launch TensorBoard" from the command palate, I get
[this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U06BB.png). It's the TensorBoard page with the default message "No dashboards are active for the current data set". The command palate command has two log directory options, "Use current working directory" and "Select another folder", but neither seem to work.

However, when I run TensorBoard normally using the terminal command

```
tensorboard --logdir=...
```

everything works fine. This makes me think my log directory and tensorboard installation are set up fine, and the issue is with VS Code or the Python extension.

I should mention I generated my logs using PyTorch and PyTorch Lightning, not Tensorflow. (And for context, I'm using macOS Big Sur)

Does anyone have any idea what the fix is?

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example that can minimize the recurrence of this problem? Also it is recommended that you try to test this feature in "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)".